# Are there any pitfalls trying to run DNN on Windows Server 2008 Web Edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-hosting, dotnetnuke, colocation, windows-server-2008-web

I am considering switching to a co-located solution running a DNN (DotNetNuke) installation and an email server that mostly just does alias forwarding.  I think I can get DNS services outside of this colocation box - but that could be an issue.

I am running this website for a non-profit group and trying to stay inexpensive.  Will Windows Server 2008 Web Edition be acceptable for running all of this?  My research so far says it will but I am looking for anyone with any experience running web edition and what sort of pitfalls does it have?

I was going to install SQL express as the backend for the DNN site. Indications are that you can't connect to SQL from outside the Web Edition box.  Does this include SQL Management studio?

Any assistance or advice on this would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Still looking for any specifics with Windows Server 2008 **Web Edition**

Answer (score 1):

We tried running DNN on Windows 2008 64-bit and 32-bit a while back. Not a great experience with intermittant failures and application hangs. We had to revert back to Windows 2003.

This was on a moderately loaded site. If you want to give them any sort of guaranteed uptime/availability I would recommend Windows 2003.

Comment: more interested in experiences with the Web Edition specifically